# Parameter tuning trick in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In normal deep learning, there requires a lot of training tricks such as inserting a normalization after maxpooling layer or augment the input image by swirling the original input.

However, parameter tuning in reinforcement learning is uniquely special for the following reasons:

1) There is no validation set for reinforcement learning.

2) We usually fake target labels in the reinforcement learning, therefore the loss sometimes did not indicate the real training performance.

I am wondering what parameter tuning experience you can share in the reinforcement learning task, e.g., the initialization setting, the reward setting, the loss setting, etc.